# Powershell - Remove duplicates from collection

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I'm returning IP/MAC addresses from Hyper-V

for VM's with multiple IP/MAC addresses i'm getting duplicated VM names, IE, if VM has 2 IP/MAC i'm getting 2 same VM names, if it has 3 IP/MAC then getting 3 same VM names, VMname is stored in `$virtm` variable

```
$vms=Get-VM | Where { $_.State –eq ‘Running’ } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 


 foreach($vm in $vms) {

    $out=Get-VMNetworkAdapter -vmname $vm | select VMName, MacAddress, IPAddresses

    $virtm=($out.VMName | ForEach-Object {

    $_ | Get-Unique

    })

    $ip=($out.IPAddresses | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | ? {$_ -notmatch ':'}

    }) -join " "


    $mac = ($out.MacAddress | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Insert(2,":").Insert(5,":").Insert(8,":").Insert(11,":").Insert(14,":")
}) -join ' '

     Write-Output "$virtm, $ip, $mac"

   }
```

**Current output**

```
OAP80 OAP80, 192.168.1.45 192.168.2.45, 00:15:5D:58:12:5E 00:15:5D:58:12:5F
```

**Desired output**

```
OAP80, 192.168.1.45 192.168.2.45, 00:15:5D:58:12:5E 00:15:5D:58:12:5F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm stupid

instead of

```
 $virtm=($out.VMName | ForEach-Object {

    $_ | Get-Unique

    })
```

just had to `$virtm=$out.VMName | Get-Unique`